# How do I testing error manipulation in RxJS?

Tags: rxjs

I have a DB code that might throw a MongoError. I would like to catch it and manipulate it, transforming it into my own type of error (I don't want the MongoError to be exposed to other parts of my application). So I do it as follows:

```js
// request = { deviceId: 2, name: 'Device' }
public create(request: DeviceCreationRequest): Observable<Device> {
  return fromPromise(this.model.create(request)).pipe(
    catchError(err =>
      throwError({ code: 409, body: { msg: 'duplicated key', key: err.keyPattern } }))
    map(DeviceRepository.toDevice));
```

It works fine in the endpoint, but I don't know how to test it.

```js
it('create with duplicated key', done => {
  const request = { deviceId: 2, name: 'Device' };
  repository.create(request).pipe(
    catchError(err => {
      console.log(err);  // shows the original MongoDB error
      return of(undefined);
    }),
    flatMap(_ => repository.getAll()))
  .subscribe(devices => {/* some assertions */});
});
```

Looks like my test `catchError` overwrites the old one (or something). And if I don't do it, the test case will error out.

Comment: mock this.model.create() to throw an error or return a promise.reject()

Comment: The error is happening without any need to mock it. The problem is that I cannot catch it in the test (well, I can catch the initial error from MongoDB, but not the one I transformed it into). Please take a closer look at the code and question description.